# Error : No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

Situation:
I developed web app with blazor server that is connecting to my web api. Web Api use swagger, and I use nswagstudio to generate c# proxy class and interface that i am using in Web App.
Web App is secured with azure ad login (Microsoft.Identity) and Web Api is secured by bearer token in http header (also checked agains azure ad).
I am adding WebApi generated proxy using code:

my extension method to register api proxy:

```
public static void AddMyProxy(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var uri = new MyProxySettings().ApiUrl;

    services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceClient>(config => 
    {
        string token = "";
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        if (httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
        {
            var tokenService = serviceProvider.GetService<ITokenAcquisition>();
            try
            {
                token = tokenService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { @"api://xxxxx-yyy-aa-bb-cc/my_scope" }).Result;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "error while loading token for current user, try to login again");
            }
        }

        config.BaseAddress = uri;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }
    });
}
```

and in WebApp ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSignIn(Configuration, subscribeToOpenIdConnectMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);
services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { @"api://xxxxx-yyy-aa-bb-cc/my_scope" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
services.AddMyProxy();
```

When i try to acquire bearer token while initializing DI I always get exception

```
No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call
```

But i tried to do almost the same in blazor page and it works with http200 and api returns data back without any problems

```
@code{ 
private string token {get;set;}
private List<MyDto> data {get;set;}

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try

    {
        token = await tokenService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { @"api://xxxxx-yyy-aa-bb-cc/my_scope" });
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://localhost:44365/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        IMyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(httpClient);
        var data = await client.ApiV1SomeMethodAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
}
```

So how to register my proxy and acquire token to use it in api calls while i am registering DI service? Or are there any other approach that should i try?

Thanks for any reply and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was pulling ITokenAcquisition service from service collection. When I used httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService its works fine.

```
public static void AddMyProxy(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var settings = new MyProxySettings();
            var uri = settings.ApiUrl;
            var scope = settings.Scope;
            services.AddHttpClient<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceClient>(async config => 
            {
                string token = "";
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
                if (httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
                {
                    **var tokenService = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();**
                    try
                    {
                        token = await tokenService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { scope });
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        //logger.LogError(ex, "error while loading token for current user, try to login again");
                    }
                }

                config.BaseAddress = uri;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Wow ... I have spent the past day and a bit hitting this same issue and your solution also worked for me.  I followed all of the MS documentation and guidance and nothing discussed your approach.   Do you know why it only work from the htttpContextAccessor and not from service collection?

Comment: Not sure, since i was also struggling for few hours, i was happy that it works, i was not looking deeper

Comment: Calls to services.BuildServicesProvider are considered by the ASPNET core 5, See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ASP0000 Is there an apporved way of getting hold of ITokenAcquisition within AddHttpClient?