# MSAL.NET redirect loop when using graphApi in MVC & blazor with multiple instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a blazor component that aims to simplify managing users and group of an enterprise application in my ASP.NET MVC website. When I run the code locally, everything works just fine. However, when I deploy my code on the dev environment (in AKS) the code only works if I run one replica.

When I use multiple instances and I try to access the page that calls my blazor component, the page ends up in a redirect loop, and finally shows the Microsoft login interface with an error mentioning that the login was not valid.

This is how my code looks like:

```
# program.cs
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
var cacheOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureTableStorageCacheOptions").Get<AzureTableStorageCacheOptions>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

builder.Services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
});

builder.Services.AddDistributedAzureTableStorageCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = cacheOptions.ConnectionString;
    options.TableName = cacheOptions.TableName;
    options.PartitionKey = cacheOptions.PartitionKey;
    options.CreateTableIfNotExists = true;
    options.ExpiredItemsDeletionInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
});

builder.Services.AddSession();

...
```

```
# The controller that calls the blazor component
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "Application.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserManagement()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "Application.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All" };
        try
        {
            await _tokenAcquisition
                .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And this is what happens:

[image]
[image]

If the page loads, I can see this exception in the pod logs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the culprit was:

```
#my controller
    await _tokenAcquisition
                .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Which we were using initially to reauthenticate the graph api component when we were using InMemoryCache.

There is no need to get the access token again when using DistributedTokenCache, and actually that was causing the token to get saved / invalidated in an infinite loop.

Also, in my blazor component, I had to do use the consent handler to force a login:

```
    private async Task<ServicePrincipal> GetPrincipal(AzureAdConfiguration addConfiguration)
    {
        try
        {
            return await GraphClient.ServicePrincipals[addConfiguration.PrincipalId].Request()
            .Select("id,appRoles, appId")
            .GetAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The tenant actually needs to provide admin consent to your web API for the scopes you want to use for replicas for the token taken from cache.

Also when `AuthorizeForScopes` attribute is specified with scopes ,this needs the exact scopes that is required by that api. `MsalUiRequiredException` gets thrown in case of incorrect scopes for that api  and  results in a challenge to user.

2. This error may also occur even when the `acquiretokensilent` call will not have a  valid cookie anymore  for authentication in cache .Please check how acquiretokensilent call works from here in msal [net acquire token silently | microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)
3. When valid scopes are given , please make sure the permissions are granted consent by the admin directly from portal or during user login authentication.

[image]

> Also as  a work around try to use  use `httpContextAccessor` to access
> token after authentication .

**Reference**: [c# - Error : No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518766/error-no-account-or-login-hint-was-passed-to-the-acquiretokensilent-call)

Comment: Scopes were correct in AAD, sadly. The issue was caused by `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` being called in the controller.